# Hiding contents of jsp according to permission given to user in spring security

Tags: spring-security

In my project there are 4 tables:

```
Users
-----
Id
First_Name
Last_Name
....
...
role_id foreign key referenced by Role

Role
----
Id
Role_Name

Permission
----------
Id
Permission_Name

RolePermissions
---------------
Role_Id foreign key
Permission_Id foreign Key
```

I need to hide contents of welcome.jsp according to the role_id(Users) having permission from Permission table. In which I defined Permission_Name like **_.user.create, _**.user.view etc. I searched a lot but could not found the specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using struts2 also. then Please check this website.

[Spring Security Example](http://technicalminds.in/spring/struts2-spring-security-example-2/)

Comment: thanks for ur reply, But I am using Spring MVC for view and controller layer and for dao I am using hibernate, Using annotation I am doing all that work. So please response accordingly.